# Замена текста в столбце с помощью Google Apps Script

Tags: google-apps-script

В столбце `A` находятся данные в виде текста

```
[
  [(q/log/arr],
  [asj89/log/arrwer],
  [asj12/log/arrwer0/io9],
  [ty/asjrt2/log/arrwer/tr09)`]
]
```

и т.д.

Подскажите, пожалуйста, скрипт, чтобы заменить в столбце `A` слово `log` на слово `rep`. А так же убрать все пробелы в столбце `A`.

Comment: Причем тут [tag:google-apps-script]?

Comment: Вы имеете в виду, что используется Google Spreadsheets и те данные, что вы привели через запятую - отдельно в каждой ячейке находятся? Если так - то можно и без скрипта - формулами. Или задача чисто скриптом? Покажите Ваш скрипт, что у Вас там не получилось.

Comment: @СергейПряничкин, скорей всего там ничего нет - обычный поиск халявы.

Comment: Да, нужно скриптом отредактировать данные в столбце. Формула не подходит иначе бы я и не спрашивал. К сожалению скрипта нет, так как я даже не смог найти примера.

Comment: @Sergun, вы должны прилагать минимум усилий. Хотя бы получить данные диапазона, а потом написать `??? что делать дальше?`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Для данных

```
|            A                |
|-----------------------------|
| (q/log/arr                  |
| asj89/log/arrwer dsfg sdg f |
| asj12/log/arrw  er0/io9     |
| ty/asjrt2/log/arrwer/tr09)` |
```

подход обычно такой

```
function myFunction() {
  var range = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet()
    .getRange("Sheet1!A:A");
  range.setValues(range.getValues().map(blackBox_));
}

function blackBox_(row){
  return [row[0].replace("log", "rep").replace(/\s+/g, "")];
}
```

Результат

```
|            A                |
|-----------------------------|
| (q/rep/arr                  |
| asj89/rep/arrwerdsfgsdgf    |
| asj12/rep/arrwer0/io9       |
| ty/asjrt2/rep/arrwer/tr09)` |
```

Через формулу

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(REGEXREPLACE(REGEXREPLACE(A:A,"log","reg")," ",""))
```

Comment: Спасибо, с формулами у меня трудности нет, а вот скрипт пока дается с трудом.

Comment: Подскажите, где можно почитать о кодах в 'replace(/\s+/g, "")'

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace